# Given an array of ints, return true if the array contains both 1's and 3's, at least one each

Tags: java, arrays

This Java code suppose to return true if the array have both 1s and 3s at least one each.This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
public boolean find13(int[] nums) {

   boolean array = true; 

   for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 

      if(nums[i] == 1 && nums[i] == 3){
      }

      else{
          array = false;
      }
   }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Just an fyi, your function as written would have NEVER given you the correct answer. All it does is set the output to false times the number of integers you pass in as your nums parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake when I was typing it. I'm fixing it right now

Answer (score 2):

```
bool bHasOnes = false;
bool bHasThrees = false;
bool bRetVal = false;
for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
{
    //if you find a 1 or 3 set the boolean values for them
    if(nums[i] == 1)
        bHasOnes = true;
    if(nums[i] == 3)
        bHasThrees = true;
    //if we found both break out of the loop, no need to continue
    if(bHasThrees == true && bHasOnes == true)
    {    
         bRetVal = true;
         break;
    }
}
return bRetVal;
```

Comment: I want to -1 for the Hungarian notation though... OP, DON'T use that in your variable naming.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

If you're interested in Java 8 streams. Try this one-liner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[]{1, 2, 4}));
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[]{2, 3, 4}));
}

public static boolean find1_3(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums).filter(n -> n == 1 || n == 3).distinct().count() == 2;
}
```

It filters out all numbers except 1 and 3, then `distinct()` the result of the filter.  If you have a count of 2 then 1 & 3 are in the array, otherwise false.

Results:

```
true
false
false
```

### Old Answer

Don't want to copy @Cruentus_Nex answer (+1 to you) so here's a variation without using flags

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}));
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[] {1, 2, 4}));
    System.out.println(find1_3(new int[] {2, 3, 4}));
}

public static boolean find1_3(int[] num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] == 1 || num[i] == 3) {
            // Found first match
            int first = num[i];
            // Search for the next 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) {
                if (num[j] != first && (num[j] == 1 || num[j] == 3)) {
                    // Found second match
                    return true;
                }
            }
            // Didn't find second match
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Didn't find first match
    return false;
}
```

Results:

```
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Define two booleans. When you encounter a 3, set one of them to `true`; when 1, set the other to `true`.

Return `true` if both booleans are `true` (`return one && three;`).

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way of doing it,

```
boolean find13(int[] nums){
    boolean[] results = new boolean[]{false, false};
    for(int n : nums){
        if(!results[0] && n == 1){
            results[0] = true;
        } else if(!results[1] && n == 3){
            results[1] = true;
        } else if(results[0] && results[1]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution uses the contains function of a java.util.List. An example implementation would be like:

```
public boolean find13(int nums[])
{
   List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nums);
   return list.contains(1) && list.contains(3);
}
```

This solution is way more concise than checking each value yourself, but may not be the fastest if you have a very big array as it has to first convert the array to a list and then search for the values.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
  public boolean lucky13(int[] nums) {
      for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-1;i++){
        if((nums[i]==1)||(nums[i]==3)){
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public boolean lucky13(int[] nums) {
int count1 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
for (int num : nums) {
    if (num == 1)
        count1++;
    if (num == 3)
        count3++;}
return count1 == 0 && count3 == 0;}
```

Comment: What does this add to the already existing answers?

Comment: No one before thought of using counters, for me this way was the simplest